# compute matrix distance using dynamic programming

Tags: r, dynamic, matrix

I have a matrix composing values 0, 1, and 2. 99% of the values are 0. The matrix has 1 million rows and 700 columns. There will be at least one non-zero values each row.

I need to compute the distance between each pair of columns using this formula for distance between column x and y:
D=(Sum(|xi-yi|)/2L for i from 1 to L, L=1 million, i.e. the number of rows.

I wrote a piece of R code but it's taking too long to compute, is it possible to use dynamic programing to do it faster? Here is my code:

```
#mac is the matrix
nCols=ncol(mac)
nRows=nrow(mac)
#the pairwise distance matrix
distMat=matrix(data=-1,nrow=nCols,ncol=nCols)

abs.dist=function(x){return(abs(x[1]-x[2]))} 

for(i in 1:(nCols-1)){
    for(j in (i+1):nCols){
        d1=apply(mac[,c(i,j),1,abs.dist)
        k=sum(d1)/(2*nRows)
        distMat[i,j]=k
        distMat[j,i]=k
    }
}

for(i in 1:nCols) distMat[i,i]=0
```

Thanks a lot for any help?

Comment: I think you're killing performance by using `apply` to calculate absolute differences. Subtraction and finding the absolute values are vectorized, so you can simply do `d1 <- abs(mac[,i]-mac[,j])`

Comment: BTW, you could do `diag(distMat) <- 0` in the last line

Comment: With a matrix this large, you may think about moving to using parallel processing and `Rcpp`. Here is some code that you should be able to adapt: [Parallel Distance Matrix in R with Rcpp](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/parallel-distance-matrix/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will just summarize what is in the comments already:

```
#mac is the matrix
nCols=ncol(mac)
nRows=nrow(mac)
#the pairwise distance matrix
distMat=matrix(data=-1,nrow=nCols,ncol=nCols)

for(i in 1:(nCols-1)){
    for(j in (i+1):nCols){
        d1=abs(mac[,i]-mac[,j])
        k=sum(d1)/(2*nRows)
        distMat[i,j]=k
        distMat[j,i]=k
    }
}

diag(distMat) <- 0
```

This is approximately 100 times faster for a 2000x500 matrix.
It took about half a minute for a 1e6x700 matrix.

Comment: Thanks for the summary and the key point made by Marat! Didn't realize `apply` was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Computing a distance matrix means you need (n^2-n)/2 operations. I'm not surprised it is taking a while.

Since you need all pairs, these calculations have to be done independently. Dynamic programming will not help. DP helps when you build the solution from smaller parts. Everything here is independent so DP won't help (as far as I know).

You said most entries are 0. Try looking at a sparse matrix library. This [blog post](http://www.johnmyleswhite.com/notebook/2011/10/31/using-sparse-matrices-in-r/) may give you some ideas for doing this in R.

Comment: Thanks and I'll check out the blog. I don't know if I understand dynmaic programming completely, but there might be a lot wasted computation here. For example, if a pair of column can be converted into a pattern, say, number of 00 pair, 01 pair, 02, 12, and 22 pair. Then the distance can be saved and re-used for other pairs with the same pattern.

Comment: I think you would waste a lot of effort for minimal gain doing it that way. DP is a specific optimization algorithm where a global optimum is computed by solving optimal subproblems. In the realm of matrices, a common DP application is determining the optimal multiplication order. Have a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_chain_multiplication#A_Dynamic_Programming_Algorithm).

Comment: I agree the gain might be little in this case since computing the pattern might be even slower than computing the distance (unless there is a way to do it bit-wise). But in problems where the former is much faster than the latter, this approach could speed up the run.